# "[adjective] and [adjective] [noun]" -- Should the noun be singular or plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

In a scientific paper I submitted, a reviewer suggested that I change the sentence

> The operation just substitutes "(m, l)" with "m" on both the sender and the receiver side.

to

> The operation just substitutes "(m, l)" with "m" on both the sender and the receiver sides.

by changing the last word from singular to plural.

There is only *one* sender side and only *one* receiver side, so my intuition tells me to use the former version, since

- one would clearly write "...both the sender side and the receiver side" and
- I'd also write "The green and the blue box are standing on the table" (instead of "boxes").

However, I failed to find a grammatical rule for this, and English is not my main language. Is the reviewer right? And why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first sentence features ellipsis, that is, the omission of elements which are recoverable from the linguistic context or the situation. A full version would be *on both the sender side and the receiver side*. Once we reach the end of the sentence we can recover *side* and place it in our minds after *sender*. That’s not too difficult to do because the missing element occurs within a few words. However, some readers might be uncomfortable in performing that little bit of linguistic gymnastics, and that is presumably what the reviewer felt.

The answer to your question is that both sentences are grammatical, and both convey the same meaning. If you think your readers might have difficulty with the omission of *side* after *sender*, then use the version that uses the plural: *on both the sender and the receiver sides.* Alternatively, use the full version of the ellipted form with the singular: *on both the sender side and the receiver side*.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the full version is _on both the sender side and the receiver side_, and that the first _side_ is deleted by a conjunction reduction rule. Either way, there's two sides involved.

Comment: @John Lawler. Thank you, John. That's what I intended to say. Now edited.

Answer (score 1):

From a native speaker:

When you say "There is only one sender side and only one receiver side" that is by definition plural.  There are two sides. Use the plural.

When you suggest "The green and the blue box are standing on the table" (instead of "boxes"), that is not correct English.  One box that is colored green and blue is "the green and (not 'the') blue **box is**..."  Two boxes would be "The green and the blue **boxes are**..."