# Using "are" when referring to the sum of different categories of information

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

I know that the word "infomation" is always singular in English. However, is it grammatically correct to use "are" when refering to sum of different categories of information (e.g., in the following sentence)?

"In this approach, the semantic and location information are obfuscated independently of each other."

Comment: Yes, because *are* applies to *semantic information* and *location information*, not simply to *information*.

Comment: Also related: [“{adjective} and {adjective} {noun}” — Should the noun be singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111152/adjective-and-adjective-noun-should-the-noun-be-singular-or-plural)